# How to say that $f(x,y)$ is true for all x but only some y.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have to translate an English sentence into logical statements using quantifiers, and I think I'm on the right track but something doesn't feel right about this. I'm not really sure how I should take "as long as y satisfies..." into consideration.

> For all $\epsilon>0$, for all real numbers $x$, one an find a real number $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ as long as $y$ satisfies $|y-x|<\delta$.

My proposed solution follows:

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ \exists\delta>0,\ \exists y\ni |y-x|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

And as a secondary part of the question, I have to negate that statement:

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\ \exists x\in\mathbb{R},\ \forall\delta>0,\ \forall y,\ |y-x|<\delta\wedge |f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that what you have on the grey box is **not** a statement. The variable $y$ isn't quantified. That formula is devoided of meaning.

Presumably the intent is that $y$ is **universally** quantified and its quantifier should be the inner-most one, so you get the definition of [continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions).  Thus your statement is:

$$\forall x\in \Bbb R\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta >0\color{red}{\forall }y\in \Bbb R\left(|y-x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon\right)$$

and negating you get
$$\exists x\in \Bbb R \exists \varepsilon>0\forall \delta >0\color{red}\exists y\in \Bbb R\left(|y-x|<\delta \land |f(x)-f(y)|\ge \varepsilon\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

"As long as" signifies the antecedent of a conditional (the "if" part). With a little switch in notation to make it cleaner, you could write

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ \exists\delta>0,\ \forall y \in \mathbb{R}\;\; [y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta) \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon].$$

Let me know if you run into trouble negating that.

Comment: You need to stick a $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ before your square brackets there.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thank you!